# Android Sms gateway troubles

Tags: php, android, sms, sms-gateway

So I'm currently trying to develop some Sms service for one site on which I work. I'm using an Androip app called Sms Gateway. For the purposes of testing because it is my first time I just copy/paste the code from there website.

Here is the original:

```
<?php

/*
This demo shows how to handle requests from SMS Gateway with full UTF-8 support and send reply SMS back
*/

//setup PHP UTF-8 stuff
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output('UTF-8');


//read parameters from HTTP Get URL
$phone = $_GET["phone"];
$smscenter = $_GET["smscenter"];
$text_utf8 = rawurldecode($_GET["text"]);

//if parameters are not present in HTTP url, they can be also present in HTTP header
$headers = getallheaders();
if (empty($phone)) {
        $phone = $headers["phone"];
}
if (empty($smscenter)) {
        $smscenter = $headers["smscenter"];
}
if (empty($text_utf8)) {
        $text_utf8 = rawurldecode($headers["text"]);
}



//create reply SMS
$reply_utf8 = mb_strtoupper($text_utf8); // mare reply message uppercased input message

//write reply to HTTP header
$reply_header = rawurlencode($reply_utf8);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("text: $reply_header"); //if you don't want reply sms, comment out this this line


// Debug outputs:
//echo "phone = $phone\n";
//echo "smscenter = $smscenter\n";
//echo "text_utf8 = $text_utf8\n";
//echo "reply_utf8 = $reply_utf8\n";
?>
```

And this is mine which runs on the server:

```
<?php
/*
This demo shows how to handle requests from SMS Gateway with full UTF-8 support and send reply SMS back
*/

//setup PHP UTF-8 stuff
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output('UTF-8');


//read parameters from HTTP Get URL
$phone = $_GET["phone"];
$smscenter = $_GET["smscenter"];
$text_utf8 = rawurldecode($_GET["text"]);

//if parameters are not present in HTTP url, they can be also present in HTTP header
$headers = getallheaders();
if (empty($phone)) {
        $phone = $headers["phone"];
}
if (empty($smscenter)) {
        $smscenter = $headers["smscenter"];
}
if ($text_utf8 == "a") {
        sendResponse("Give me somthing so I know you are working!!!!!!!!");
}
else{
        sendResponse("Bad response");
}

function sendResponse($t){
    //write reply to HTTP header
    $reply_header = rawurlencode($t);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header("text:".$t); //if you don't want reply sms, comment out this this line

}


// Debug outputs:
//echo "phone = $phone\n";
//echo "smscenter = $smscenter\n";
//echo "text_utf8 = $text_utf8\n";
//echo "reply_utf8 = $reply_utf8\n";
?>
```

When I check the logs I get Http response 200. Don't know what to do, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Hi @Zeljko welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be a little more clear as to what your problem is? A http status code of 200 should mean everything worked, as per http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Comment: Yeah 200 Status code means everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't then I be getting the message "Give me somthing so I know you are working!!!!!!!!" as a response. See the code up above. I know that 200 means that everything is ok. But it bugs me that I didn't got any message with text in return just blank space. Thanks for fast reponses.